# reset custom field when navigation menu is deleted in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I have a custom field associated with all posts and pages. It's a dropdown of all the navigation menus. 
here is how I'm populating the custom field drop-down: (the field name is custom_menu...)

```
function acf_load_menu_field_choices( $field ) {

    // reset choices
    $field['choices'] = array();

    $menus = get_terms( 'nav_menu', array( 'hide_empty' => true ) );

    $blank_list = json_encode(array( "name" => "Select Menu", "slug" => "")); 
    $blank_list = json_decode($blank_list);
    array_unshift($menus, $blank_list);
    foreach ( $menus as $val ) {

        $value = $val->slug;
        $label = $val->name;

        $field['choices'][ $value ] = $label;
    }

    // return the field
    return $field;

}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=custom_menu', 'acf_load_menu_field_choices');
```

Here is a common menu location that I'm using on each page:

```
function register_custom_menu() {  //function to register new menu
     register_nav_menu('custom-menu',__( 'Custom Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_menu' );
```

And then I'm assigning a menu dynamically to the location `custom-menu` based on the custom field menu on each page.

and here is the function the fires on each page when it's loaded:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_load_custom_menu", "load_custom_menu");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_load_custom_menu", "load_custom_menu");
function load_custom_menu(){
    $post_id = $_POST['page_id'];
    $page_custom_menu = get_field('custom_menu', $post_id);
    if(empty($page_custom_menu) || $page_custom_menu == "primary") return;
    $locations = get_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations' );
    if(!empty($locations)) {
        foreach($locations as $locationId => $menuValue) { 
            if($locationId == "custom-menu") $menu = get_term_by('slug', $page_custom_menu, 'nav_menu');  
            if(isset($menu)) { $locations[$locationId] = $menu->term_id; }
        } 
    } 
    set_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations', $locations);

    wp_nav_menu( array( 
        'theme_location' => 'custom-menu', 
        'menu_id' => 'primary-menu', 
        'menu_class' => 'main-nav underline-decoration l-to-r-line level-arrows-on outside-item-remove-margin',
        'container' => false
        ) 
    );

    wp_die();
}
```

This ajax function fires on `ready` event and recieves a `POST` value called `page_id`. This function checks the custom field value of the given `page_id` for `custom-menu` and assign that menu to the `menu location` called `custom-menu`.

Here's my JavaScript in case you need to have a look on it:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    let customMenu;
    let page_id = script_vars.postID;
    $.post(dtLocal.ajaxurl, { action: "load_custom_menu", page_id: page_id }, resp => customMenu = resp);
    $(window).scroll(() => {
        if(customMenu !== "0"){
            $("#phantom .main-nav").remove();
            $("#phantom .menu-box").html(customMenu);
        }
    })
})
```

This is how my code is working, And everything works fine up to this point.

**Now here is the problem**
Whenever I delete a Navigation menu from **Appearence>Menus>Delete Menu**  My custom Menu starts behaving unexpectedly because the custom field value is still pointing to the deleted Menu.
What I want to do here is, **I want to Delete the Custom Field whenever a menu is deleted**. *First I want to get the slug of a deleted menu and then find the custom field value with that slug and then finally, delete or reset that custom field.*

Comment: You are looking for action "wp_delete_nav_menu" that will take one argument - menu id. The problem that at that point your nav menu will be deleted, so you won't be able to take it slug. Is it possible that you use ID as custom_field value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for action `wp_delete_nav_menu` that will take one argument - `menu id`. The problem that at that point your nav menu will be deleted, so you won't be able to take it slug.

If it is possible that you can store nav menu ID instead of slug, that would simplify things greatly.

In `acf_load_menu_field_choices` replace:

```
foreach ( $menus as $val ) {
    $value = $val->term_id;
    $label = $val->name;
    $field['choices'][ $value ] = $label;
}
```

And in `load_custom_menu`:

```
$page_custom_menu = get_field('custom_menu', $post_id);
if(empty($page_custom_menu) || $page_custom_menu == /* Should be your primary menu ID */) return;
$locations = get_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations' );
if(!empty($locations)) {
    foreach($locations as $locationId => $menuValue) {
        if($locationId == "custom-menu") $menu = get_term_by('id', $page_custom_menu, 'nav_menu');
        if(isset($menu)) { $locations[$locationId] = $menu->term_id; }
    }
}
```

After those changes you will need to rewrite `custom_menu` in all posts\pages.

After that, following function will remove all related fields when you delete menu. It has been tested only on typical ACF field (string) instead of custom, but should work just fine with your code as well.

```
add_action('wp_delete_nav_menu', 'delete_all_acf_fields_with_menu', 10, 1);
function delete_all_acf_fields_with_menu($term_id) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'        => array('post', 'page'),
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'meta_key' => 'custom_menu',
        'meta_value' => $term_id,
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    if( $posts ) {
        foreach( $posts as $p ) {
            delete_field('custom_menu', $p->ID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I already modified my code and implemented the solution similar to yours.

Answer (score 2):

Menus in WordPress are just [terms in a taxonomy](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L18). So you can use all of the term hooks.

In particular the [pre_delete_term](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1738) hook.

```
add_action( 'pre_delete_term', 'my_func' );
function my_func($term, $taxonomy){

  // Check the taxonomy is really 'menu', then check term
}
```

Comment: `nav_menu_item` is just an items in a menu, not a menu itself. While deleting menu will trigger deleting items (I guess), this hook will be executed several times and will not be an efficient solution.

Comment: Yep, I have edited the answer with the proper way to do it with terms.